# how to make a plot from table that i made

Tags: r

```
f1 <- c(AppliedSci[1, 27], AppliedSci[1, 28], AppliedSci[1, 29], AppliedSci[1, 30])
f2 <- c(Arts[1, 27], Arts[1, 28], Arts[1, 29], Arts[1, 30])
f3 <- c(Business[1, 27], Business[1, 28], Business[1, 29], Business[1, 30])
f4 <- c(Cmns[1, 27], Cmns[1, 28], Cmns[1, 29], Cmns[1, 30])
f5 <- c(Education[1, 27], Education[1, 28], Education[1, 29], Education[1, 30])
f6 <- c(Envir[1, 27], Envir[1, 28], Envir[1, 29], Envir[1, 30])
f7 <- c(Health[1, 27], Health[1, 28], Health[1, 29], Health[1, 30])
f8 <- c(Sci[1, 27], Sci[1, 28], Sci[1, 29], Sci[1, 30])
table1 <- matrix(c(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8), nrow = 8)
dimnames(table1) <- list(c('Applied Sci', 'Arts', 'Business', 'Cmns', 'Education', 'Envir', 'Health', 'Sci'), c('2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'))
print(table1)
```

I made a table of 8 different data sets.

```
           2015     2016     2017     2018    
Applied Sci 2.738711 2.925577 3.337963 2.809579
Arts        2.799184 2.942416 3.302009 2.827511
Business    2.842297 2.947728 3.287924 2.847484
Cmns        2.858647 2.930016 3.30618  2.880631
Education   2.635278 2.896335 2.74187  2.905071
Envir       2.65874  2.881061 2.695469 2.929655
Health      2.671453 2.86696  2.704806 2.884058
Sci         2.689576 2.919287 2.787219 2.881914
```

And this is a table that I made from 8 different data sets.
I would like to make a plot that has Year on x-axis and GPA on y-axis.

```
matplot(t(table1), type = "l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "GPA", ylim = c(2.50,3.50))
```

I used the "matplot" code to make a plot. But the thing is x-axis is kind of weird.
[image]

As you see, the x-axis shows 1 to 4. When I changed x-axis from 2015 to 2018 by using **xlim = c(2015,2018)** it does not show any graph.

Is there any way that I can make a plot properly?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
matplot(2015:2018, t(table1), type = "l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "GPA", ylim = c(2.50,3.50), xaxt = "n")
axis(1, 2015:2018)
```

Output

[image]